# $Var(U|T)=0$ Can I say that exists g such that U=g(T)? Why?

Tags: probability

Let $T$ be a sufficient statistic for $\theta$, and $U$ an unbiased estimator of $\tau(\theta)$. If $Var_{\theta}(U|T)=Var(U|T)=0$, then can I say that there exists a function $g$ such that $U=g(T)$?Why?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try $g(T) = \mathcal{E}(U|T)$.

Comment: Forget every hypothesis except that $E(U^2\mid T)=V^2$ where $V=E(U\mid T)$, then $E((U-V)^2\mid T)=0$ almost surely, hence $E((U-V)^2)=0$ hence $U=V$ almost surely. Since $V=g(T)$ for some measurable $g$, you are done.

Comment: @Did Thanks for the answer. ;)